# Why is this image not showing up on My Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I am java script and html learner, i still don't know everything yet. The problem i am having is that my image is not showing up on the canvas. (There is a gradient).

I looked online and couldn't find anything of need.
Here is the HTML and Java Script code i am using

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var GamePiece;


function startGame() {
  "use strict";
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 0);
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#85E2FF");
  grd.addColorStop(0, "blue");

  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1300, 600);

  GamePiece = document.createElement("myImg");
  GamePiece.setAttribute("width", "175");
  GamePiece.setAttribute("height", "175");

  GamePiece.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(GamePiece, 70, 70);
  };

  GamePiece.src = "GamePiece.png";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Demo.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class="Header" id="MyHeader">
      <a href="MyGame.html">Home</a>
      <a class="active" href="Demo.html"> JavaScript Game </a>
      <div id="Header-right">
        <a href="About"> About </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Title">
    <h1> Game Purely Made from JavaScript </h1>
  </div>

  <center>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <button onClick="startGame()" id="Play">Play Now</button>
  </center>

  <script src="Demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: The image won't show up on the canvas

Comment: I am doing all of this in Dreamweaver and i have one error, which i don;t think means anything. The error is that, the function startGame() is defined but never used. I do not think that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need an [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object to draw. See the documentation for [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

You are using `createElement`, but passing it a string of `"myImg"` which isn't a valid tag. You should create the `Image` object instead and set its source and load events like you were doing:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var GamePiece;


function startGame() {
  "use strict";
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 0);
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#85E2FF");
  grd.addColorStop(0, "blue");

  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1300, 600);

  GamePiece = new Image(175, 175);

  GamePiece.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 70, 70);
  };

  GamePiece.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/175";
}
```

```html
<center>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <button onClick="startGame()" id="Play">Play Now</button>
</center>
```